# MySQL datetime to just date

Tags: mysql, update, datatypes

Currently I have a table containing a column of type `datetime`. I have no need for the use of the HH:MM:SS that trail the variables stored in this column. I just need the YYYY-MM-DD. Is there any way to change the column to store just the YY-MM-DD?

If yes, would this corrupt any of the data?

If no, would the solution lie in creating a completely new column?

Comment: You can [change the column type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html): `ALTER TABLE <table> CHANGE <datetime_col_name> <datetime_col_name> DATE;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the manual [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime), you can simply use the `DATE()` function.

> ```
>  DATE(expr)
>
> Extracts the date part of the date or datetime expression expr.
>
> mysql> SELECT DATE('2003-12-31 01:02:03');
>         -> '2003-12-31'
> ```

It is designed for precisely your use case. Although the quote is from the 5.7 manual, it works right back to at least 5.0. You don't have to worry about corrupting your data.

If you are using 5.7, you can use a [generated column](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/):

> The syntax is:
>
> TYPE   [ GENERATED ALWAYS ]   AS   (  )   [
>   VIRTUAL|STORED ] [ UNIQUE [KEY] ]   [ [PRIMARY] KEY ]   [ NOT NULL ]
>   [ COMMENT  ]

```
MyDate DATE AS (DATE(My_Date_Time_Field))  -- or similar, not tested
```

This avoids throwing away data which **might** be useful later and nicely tidies your `SQL` syntax.

However, if you're using an earlier version of MySQL, you can always generate this `DATE()` part on the fly, which given the relatively simple syntax, shouldn't be too problematic.